# Not allow user to enter same keyword, sometimes it works, sometimes don't, jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create a program that not allow user to enter the same keyword, I simplified my code like below, what have I done wrong? sometimes it works, but sometimes it will consider every keyword is same.

```js
$(".tag_link").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var href = $.trim($(this).attr('href'));//trim href value
    var txtToMatch = $('.result_tag').text();//must be a class, becuase id represent one.
    var iMatch = txtToMatch.indexOf(href); 
  
    if (iMatch !== -1 ) {
        //same keywords, not allow to enter
        // put action here
        alert('same keyword');
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="result_tag" href="apple">apple</a>
<a class="result_tag" href="berry">berry</a>
<a class="result_tag" href="banana">banana</a>

<div>
    <a class="tag_link" href="apple">apple</a>
    <a class="tag_link" href="watermelon" >watermelon</a>
</div>
```

Comment: `$('.result_tag').text()` returns the text of the very first element, not a combination of all matched elements

Comment: what should I do to correct that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is because the `text()` method will only return the text of the first matched item in the set, not all of them concatenated. To get around this, you could use `map()` to create an array of the text values, then `indexOf` to find a specific item in that array. Try this:

```js
$(".tag_link").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var href = $.trim($(this).attr('href'));
    var txtToMatch = $('.result_tag').map(function() {
        return $(this).text();
    }).get();
  
    if ($.inArray(href, txtToMatch) !== -1 ) {
        // same keywords, not allow to enter
        // put action here
        alert('same keyword');
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="result_tag" href="apple">apple</a>
<a class="result_tag" href="berry">berry</a>
<a class="result_tag" href="banana">banana</a>

<div>
    <a class="tag_link" href="apple">apple</a>
    <a class="tag_link" href="watermelon" >watermelon</a>
</div>
```

Comment: for reason, your code txtToMatch always give me -1, so it always consider every word different, why?

Comment: I'm not sure. As you can see in snippet it works fine guven tge HTML you gave.